# Does SP2010 need FIM to synchronize users?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Does SharePoint 2010 require "Microsoft Forefront Identity Manager (FIM) service" to be enabled for user profile synchronization to function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forefront Identity Manager (FIM), formerly known as Microsoft Identity Integration Server (MIIS), is used to facilitate synchronization between multiple endpoints. For Example: (FIM sits between Active Directory and User Profile Service Application and is responsible for syncing changes between both endpoints. Without a healthy FIM, SharePoint sync isn’t possible and will fail. FIM automatically gets installed when SharePoint 2010 is installed.

One of the UPA SQL databases is called the Sync database by default. FIM utilizes the profile Sync Database to store data. So what components make up FIM?

1. Two Services

   - Forefront Identity Manager service
   - Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2010/03/20/sharepoint-2010-provisioning-user-profile-synchronization.aspx)

It most important component of UPA sync, sync will not started if FIM not available. Another thing don't start services manaully, let sharepoint handle it.

Comment: Are you saying the FIM services are started by SharePoint? How?

Comment: when you start the sync services from Central admin > manage services on server > click start on User profile syhc service" at that time sharepoint start it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FIM is an important component to set up a successful sync, and consist of two up-and-running services:

1. Forefront Identity Manager Service
2. Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service

I assume sync is being done between SharePoint UPS and Active directory?

Comment: Yes. This is for a sync between Sharepoint UPS and Active directory